# setState code is being skipped during execution in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to initialize some textfields with data from a database. Below is the code that populates the textfields if there is data or sets them to blank if not.

Everything works fine until I get to the setState towards the bottom of the code snippet. When it tries to execute the setState it skips and goes to initializing the client textfields. The problem there is that the variable _clientId is null.

```
String? _clientId;

getTrxn() async {
    if (widget.newTrxn!) {
      _companyId = ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId;

      clientFNameController.text = "";
      clientLNameController.text = "";
      clientAddress1Controller.text = "";
      clientAddress2Controller.text = "";
      clientCityController.text = "";
      clientStateController.text = "";
      clientTypeController.text = "";
      clientCellPhoneController.text = "";
      clientHomePhoneController.text = "";
      clientEmailController.text = "";

      propertyAddressController.text = "";
      propertyCityController.text = "";
      propertyStateController.text = "";
      propertyZipcodeController.text = "";
      mlsNumberController.text = "";
      contractDateController.text = "";
      contractPriceController.text = "";
      sellerDisclosure24aController.text = "";
      dueDiligence24bController.text = "";
      financing2cController.text = "";
      settlement24dController.text = "";
      inspectorCompanyController.text = "";
      inspectorPhoneController.text = "";
      inspectionDateController.text = "";
      appraiserController.text = "";
      appraiserPhoneController.text = "";
      appraisalDateController.text = "";
      closingDateController.text = "";
      walkThroughDateController.text = "";
      titleCompanyController.text = "";
      titlePhoneController.text = "";
      titleEmailController.text = "";
      mortgageCompanyController.text = "";
      mortgagePhoneController.text = "";
      mortgageEmailController.text = "";
      otherAgentController.text = "";
      otherAgentEmailController.text = "";
      otherAgentPhoneController.text = "";
      otherPartyClientController.text = "";
      otherPartyTitleCompanyController.text = "";
      trxnStatusController.text = "";
      trxnIdController.text = "";
      setState(() {
        _trxnStatus = 'Select Status';
      });
    } else {
      final DocumentSnapshot _mlsId =
          await mlsRef.doc(ref.read(usersNotifierProvider).mlsId).get();
      _mlsSearchLink = _mlsId.get('mlsNbrSearch');

      try {
        _trxnStream = _db
            .collection('company')
            .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).companyId)
            .collection('trxns')
            .doc(ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentTrxnId)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((trxnSnapshot) {
          clientTypeController.text = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientType'] ?? "";
          _clientType = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientType'] ?? "";

          _clientId = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientId'] ?? "";

          setState(() {  <<< EXECUTION SKIPS THIS
            _trxnStatus = trxnSnapshot.data()?['trxnStatus'] ?? "Select Status";
            _clientType =
                trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientType'] ?? 'Select Client Type';
            _selectedCompany = trxnSnapshot.data()?['companyId'] ?? "";
            _selectedUser = trxnSnapshot.data()?['userId'] ?? "";
            _selectedClientState = trxnSnapshot.data()?['clientState'] ?? "";
            if (trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'] == null ||
                trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'] == "") {
              _currentState = "AL";
            } else {
              _currentState = trxnSnapshot.data()?['propertyState'];
            }
          });
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }

      // Get the Client data associated with the transaction
      _clientStream =
          _db.collection('client').doc(_clientId).snapshots().listen(
        (clientSnapshot) {
          clientFNameController.text =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientFName'] ?? "";
          clientLNameController.text =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientLName'] ?? "";
          clientAddress1Controller.text =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientAddress1'] ?? "";
          clientAddress2Controller.text =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientAddress2'] ?? "";
          clientCityController.text =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientCity'] ?? "";
          clientStateController.text =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientState'] ?? "";
          clientCellPhoneController.text =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientCellPhone'] ?? "";
          clientCellPhoneController.text != "" &&
                  clientCellPhoneController.text != null
              ? _hasCellNumber = true
              : _hasCellNumber = false;
          _clientCellPhoneNumber =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientCellPhone'] ?? "";
          clientHomePhoneController.text =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientHomePhone'] ?? "";
          clientHomePhoneController.text != "" &&
                  clientHomePhoneController.text != null
              ? _hasHomeNumber = true
              : _hasHomeNumber = false;
          _clientHomePhoneNumber =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientHomePhone'] ?? "";
          clientEmailController.text =
              clientSnapshot.data()?['clientEmail'] ?? "";
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

After the execution stops on setState the variable _clientId which had a value is set to null. There is no error thrown.

Why does the execution skip the setState code and why is the variable _clientId reset to null?

Comment: Why do you need to set the state manually if you are initializing your widget? setState is used when your Widget is already been created and displayed and then you want to make runtime changes to it

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but why does the variable _clientId lose its value?

Comment: I mean I can speculate, it probably has to do with reassignment, it's being assigned null somewhere, and you will have to manually debug and find how and where off the top of my head guess something is triggering your widget to rebuild and because of that the value in your variable is set to null, Why you may ask? Even I'm not sure may be your stream sets it to null? DEBUG AND FIND OUT :)

Comment: Thanks, I have been debugging but it doesn't show anything. I will keep trying.

Comment: Try something, instead of using a field, use a getter and add a breakpoint to it, see what changes its values https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getter-and-setter-methods-in-dart/